# Searchable Visio diagram in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-visio

I am often asked why I use Word to draw diagrams instead of using Visio.  My standard reply is because you can't search for words in Visio when you're in Word.

The only way I've found so far is to convert the Word document containing a Visio diagram into PDF.  Then, magically, I can find the words in the diagrams.  Unfortunately, when I'm writing a document, it is very tedious doing that.  I am currently stuck on 2010 until the company decides it is time change.

I am a very basic Visio user.  I've gone through whatever menus I can find but I haven't found the answer yet.  Perhaps I'm not left, right, middle clicking in the right place.
Is there a way of making the words in Visio searchable in Word?

Comment: Print / convert the word document to a PDF at the end of editing, if that doesn't make the visio words searchable, then look into using OCR functions to remedy that, e,g, in Adobe Acrobat (i.e. NOT Reader).

Comment: I already do that - isn't there a way of making words in visio searchable in Word?

Comment: Using the "Adobe PDF printer" -driver isn't tedious (comes with Acrobat), you can set it to pop up (open) the just created PDF: I use it often and get searchable / selectable text. I cannot tell about embedded Visio documents though - haven't tried that.